# Feeds: Imported dates wrong by 2 hours

Tags: datetime, feeds

I'm using feeds to import a couple of xlsx-files (MS Excel). In these there are two cells, which are mapped to start/enddate in the imported nodes.

When importing from some of the xlsx, the dates are shifted by 2 hours (instead of 08:00 its changed to 10:00).

Other xlsx-files are importing the right date value.

In the date field settings I have turned off timezone conversion.

How can I solve that problem? Is there a timezone setting inside an excel-file?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are at a time zone having 2 hours difference with UTC.

Excel store time fields in UTC format. Adjusting the time in the excel to take care of this behaviour is the easiest solution (use excel formulas)

Comment: Even if I dont use any timezone conversion in the date module?